# Need a date from an array DateTimeObject

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I need formatted date-time from php array, I received it from mysql like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Holidays] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                )

       ) )
```

But I need the new array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-12-31
    [1] => 2018-12-07
)
```

Saw a post like this but it doesn't have datetimeobject

Comment: You could always ask mysql for a DATE built from the DATETIME.  I prefer keeping data operations in the database whenever my ORM etc makes that possible; after all, it's a _database_ and it's way faster at mass data operations than php will ever be ( ignoring the decrease in network overhead for sending time data you don't want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all the elements in your array are as you show in your question, you can just use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to translate the array. For example:

```
$a = array(array('Holidays' => new DateTime('2018-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'))),
           array('Holidays' => new DateTime('2018-01-26', new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'))));
print_r($a);
$a = array_map(function ($v) { return $v['Holidays']->format('Y-m-d'); }, $a);
print_r($a);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => 2018-01-01
    [1] => 2018-01-26 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/WGtN4)

Comment: Thank you so much, guess I need to read about array map. Really this helped me as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
foreach ($dates as $date) {
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Comment: Always use English as an external reference; I've edited this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is this:

```
$array=array("2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000","2018-02-01 06:10:59.000000");
```

You could try formatting your data using Date and strtotime

```
foreach($array as $date){
    echo "Date Format: ".Date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date))."<br>";
    echo "Datetime Format: ".Date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date))."<br>";
}
```

I hope it helps C: